# Azure Search Facet Sub Elements Limitation

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cognitive-search

As I have implemented azure search in my application 
I am facing one challenge that is like I am having facet which should be having around 50 sub-elements but it is returning only 10
I am looking for functionality by which I can configure max number of sub-elements

Answer (score 2):

> For each faceted field in the navigation tree, there is a **default limit of 10 values**. This default makes sense for navigation structures because it keeps the values list to a manageable size. You can override the default by assigning a value to `count`.

For example: `&facet=City,count:50`

In a facet query, you can set count to a value. You can set it higher or lower. Setting `count:50` gets the top 50 matches in facet results by document count.

However, **when document counts are high, there is a performance penalty**, so use this option judiciously.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-faceted-navigation#tips-about-result-count).